# What's the meaning of "stare down defeat"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

"Staring down defeat, Danny tries another plan."

Does it mean that because Danny does not want to admit defeat, he tries another plan? Or maybe after Danny outfaced defeat, he is now trying another plan?

Question update: I just found out that people sometimes say "staring down the barrel of defeat". I'm not sure if it means the same as "staring down defeat".

Comment: Danny has come to a staredown with defeat, as the current plan is not working. So he tries another plan.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that he's staring down at de feet, but I won't.

Comment: @HotLicks - Any ideas about this one? "Staring down defeat, Trump attempts a coronavirus reset." Do you agree with @Greybeard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED:

**to stare down**

**transitive. To stare at (someone) without being first to blink or lower one's gaze, *usually as an expression of resistance or hostility*; to outstare. Also figurative and in extended use.**

1946   T. H. White Mistress Masham's Repose xiv. 115   *Miss Brown searched out her pupil's eyes and fixed them with her own. She had a..trick of staring Maria down.*

1979   Guardian 12 Jan. 8/5   *Some measure of fiscal ‘mid-term adjustment’..is called for. So is a serious attempt to stare down the local government workers.*

Comment: That's right. What's your idea about my interpretation of the example?

Comment: Both are close, but neither is accurate. "He **fought and overcame his feelings of defeat.** Danny tried another plan."

Comment: "His feelings of defeat"?! Does it mean the same in the headline of the news in the following link or it is a matter of context? https://www.politico.com/news/2020/07/21/staring-down-an-election-trump-tries-on-a-new-coronavirus-message-377355

Comment: @TBY90 In the original, "defeat" is personified - my example removed this personification...

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could explain the headline in the above-mentioned link as well.

Comment: You should always quote the example. We should not have to go to a bare link... *Staring down defeat, Trump attempts a coronavirus reset > Fighting and overcoming his feelings of [imminent] defeat, Trump attempts a coronavirus reset.*

Comment: Thanks. I gave the link because I thought you might need the context.

Comment: I will point out that this metaphor likely derives, at least in part, from "staring down the barrel of the gun", where the person being targeted does not allow himself to be (visibly) intimidated by the threat.